# Textfield color change based on change in value

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I have multiple text fields in my jframe, on press of button some calculation is done and certain values are set in the text fields by default the text fields have yellow as bg color when the value in them is zero, how can i change the color of the fields when the value set in the textfields is more than 0?

Comment: Use a DocumentListener where you check the JTextField's text value, and then set the text field's background color based on that value.

Comment: You will of course need to first parse the text it holds into an int via `Integer.parseInt(...)`, best within a `try/catch (NumberFormatException nfe)` block.

Comment: Better still: don't use a JTextField but rather a JSpinner, since this will prevent non-numeric data entry.